# How to register SQL functions so that you can call them in JPQL or HQL queries with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to use a custom function in my HQL query, and I register a function in my database and this is my function's sql code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE user_id_var VARCHAR(64);
    SELECT 
    e.username
FROM
   users e  where e.id=30 INTO user_id_var;   
    return user_id_var;
END
```

and register it with a class as MysqlCustomDilect :

```
public class MysqlCustomDilect extends MySQLDialect{

    public MysqlCustomDilect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("getActiveUser", new StandardSQLFunction("getActiveUser"));
}

}
```

and add it with this line to hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="myProject.common.MysqlCustomDilect" />
```

and call it like this code in my dao layer :

```
@Override
    public List<Entity> getAll() {
        Session session = getSession();
        String hql = " select e.id as id,function('getActiveUser') as name from " + domainClass.getName() + " e ";
        Query query=session.createQuery(hql);
        return query.list();

    }
```

but hibernate does not know it and raise this error :

```
unexpected token: function near line 1, column 18 [ from e.id as id,function('getActiveUser') ........
```

Comment: it was misstyping , i fix it but it's not about that

Answer (score 4):

JPA supports calling user-defined functions like this:

```
select i 
from Item i 
where function( 'substring', i.name, 1, 3 ) = 'abc'" )
```

First of all, your function is not complete, you only pasted the body, but not the function name.

Second, you are concatenation strings so you are risking [SQL Injection](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/) attacks.

Third, the HQL is malformed:

from e.id

How come you are selecting from an identifier? The FROM clause should be listing an entity instead.

Therefore, the HQL is most likely:

```
select e, function('getActiveUser',) as name
from MyEntity e
```

Why do you concatenate the `domainClass.getName()`? Use Criteria API if the entity query is dynamic.

You can also register functions using the `MetadataBuilderContributor`:

```
public class SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor
        implements MetadataBuilderContributor {
         
    @Override
    public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
        metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "group_concat",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                "getActiveUsers",
                StandardBasicTypes.STRING
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And provide the custom `MetadataBuilderContributor` to Hibernate via the [`hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/) configuration property:

```
<property>
    name="hibernate.metadata_builder_contributor"
    value="com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.query.function.SqlFunctionsMetadataBuilderContributor"
</property>
```

Comment: the hql in incorrect sorry for that i fix it , check my updated question , and domainClass.getName() is dynamic and return the class name for me

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of Hibernate.

Comment: i user 4.3.10.Final

Comment: Try with Hibernate 5.2 and see if it works. Maybe it was a bug in 4.3.

Comment: i cant easily migrate to 5.2 , it has to much side effect in my code

Comment: Try using an SQL query instead.

Comment: Try writing a replicating test case using the Hibernate templates http://in.relation.to/2015/06/26/hibernate-test-case-templates/

Comment: i try with 5.1.0.Final but the problem does not fix.